# do we need the original pointer to free up memory the memory in c?

Tags: c

will this `cleanProgram()` function free up all the memory allocated by `malloc()` in `createArray()` function in the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct S_Array
{
    int *arr;
    int size;
}Array;

Array* createArray()
{
    Array* a = (Array*)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    printf("enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&a->size);
    a->arr = (int*)malloc(a->size*sizeof(int));
    printf("enter the array elements: ");
    for(int i=0; i<a->size; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a->arr[i]);
    }
    return a;
}

void cleanProgram(Array *a){
    free(a->arr);
    free(a);
}

void traverse(Array *a){
    for(int i=0; i<a->size; i++){
        printf("%d ",a->arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Array* a = createArray();
    traverse(a);
    cleanProgram(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your concern about freeing the memory?

Comment: You just need the value of the pointer, that is, the address it points to. So the way you wrote is correct.

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, i want to make sure the memory is freed completely.trying to understand memory managment.

Comment: @JardelLucca thank you, i understood how it works

Comment: In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. (and you can add a 3rd to always *Validate* the allocation succeeded *before* attempting to write to the block of memory)

Answer (score 0):

You are freeing memory correctly, but you're not checking for allocation errors, and therefore you also have a memory leak in `createArray()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct S_Array {
  int* arr;
  int size;
} Array;

Array* createArray(void) {
  Array* a = malloc(sizeof(Array));

  // let's check for errors
  if (a == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  printf("enter the size of array: ");
  scanf("%d", &a->size); // let's assume input is always correct

  a->arr = malloc(a->size * sizeof(int));

  // let's check for errors
  if (a->arr == NULL) {
    free(a); // here we avoid memory leaks
    return NULL;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
    printf("enter element arr[%d]: ", i); // clearer message
    scanf("%d", &a->arr[i]); // let's assume input is always correct
  }

  return a;
}

void cleanProgram(Array* a) {
  free(a->arr);
  free(a);
}

void traverse(Array* a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a->arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  Array* a = createArray();

  // let's check for errors
  if (a == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: cannot create array\n");
    return 1;
  }

  traverse(a);

  cleanProgram(a);
  return 0;
}
```